# Could not find or load main class after conversion libgdx project from java to kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, libgdx, desktop-application

I'veconverted my project form java to kotlin. And now I can't find any way to run my DesktopApplication.
It says:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ru.myitschool.dcrawler.desktop.DesktopLauncherKt
```

It's very old project from 2017, so it may lack some important fixes. I've used many guides and issues to make it work even to this state.
So I can't clearly describe steps to reproduce.
But I'll add that when only core was converted to kotlin, desktop application worked, but couldn't find any classes from core.
And after I converted DesktopApplication it's seems that some issues with classpath occured.
I changed configuratio of course and set it to one from kotlin.
The last thing I did was that I moved main out of object scopes. But this didn't change anything.

Version of LibGDX and/or relevant dependencies:

kotlinVersion = '1.3.61'

gdxVersion = '1.9.10'

[Desktop build.gradle](https://pastebin.com/gZhNV9XM)

[Parent build.gradle](https://pastebin.com/sPkg9CAT)

[DesktopLauncher.kt](https://pastebin.com/Zzz7DyWn)

Note that the application is correctly running if you start it by:

```
gradle desktop:run
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main class for Desktop Application is `ru.myitschool.dcrawler.desktop.DesktopLauncher`

However, in desktop/build.gradle you have:

```
project.ext.mainClassName = "ru.myitschool.dcrawler.desktop.DesktopLauncherKt"
```

Remove `Kt` at the end and everything should work.

**EDIT:** I also suggest to move your `fun main()` inside DesktopLauncher object and annotate it with `@JvmStatic`:

```kotlin
package ru.myitschool.dcrawler.desktop

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration
import ru.myitschool.dcrawler.MyGdxGame

object DesktopLauncher {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(arg: Array<String>) {
        val config = Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration()
        config.setTitle("Dungeon Crawler")
        val monitors = Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration.getMonitors() //config.setFullscreenMode(Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration.getDisplayMode(monitors[1]));
        config.setWindowedMode(1280, 720)
        Lwjgl3Application(MyGdxGame(), config)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working.

If you want to use it in object with JvmStatic, then you should use `ru.myitschool.dcrawler.desktop.DesktopLauncher`

But if main is out of object than kotlin will create new class to call it. And this is class `ru.myitschool.dcrawler.desktop.DesktopLauncherKt`